# Mock object method call using Spring Boot and Mockito

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I am trying to write a test for this Java SpringBoot's class:

> https://github.com/callistaenterprise/blog-microservices/blob/master/microservices/composite/product-composite-service/src/main/java/se/callista/microservices/composite/product/service/ProductCompositeIntegration.java

Specifically, I am trying to "mock" this method call:

```
URI uri = util.getServiceUrl("product");
```

I figured out I should "mock" the `ServiceUtils` object in order to do this. I tried this using the `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ProductCompositeServiceApplication.class)
public class ProductCompositeIntegrationTest {

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private ProductCompositeIntegration productIntegration;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    private ServiceUtils util;

    private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        Mockito.when(util.getServiceUrl("product")).thenReturn(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/test"));
        ResponseEntity<Iterable<Product>> products = productIntegration.getAllProducts();
    }
}
```

But this way it still calls the original `ServiceUtils` object, and not the "mocked" one. Also tried without the `@Autowired` annotation at the `ProductCompositeIntegration`, but this results in a `NullPointerException`.

What am I doing wrong?

---

My main class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ProductCompositeServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductCompositeServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The `ServiceUtils` object that I am trying to mock is specified in a class, annotated with Spring's `@Component` annotation to inject it into the other classes using `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I managed to solve this problem.

I dropped the

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ProductCompositeServiceApplication.class)
```

annotations aboved the test class.

I marked the class that I was testing with `@InjectMocks` and the dependencies with `@Mock`:

```
public class ProductCompositeIntegrationTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private ProductCompositeIntegration productIntegration;

    @Mock
    private ServiceUtils util;

    private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
        productIntegration.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void someTests() {
        when(util.getServiceUrl("product")).thenReturn(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/test"));
        //Test code...
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best approach ("the Spring way"), but this worked for me.

This article made it all clear to me: http://rdafbn.blogspot.be/2014/01/testing-spring-components-with-mockito.html

Comment: I liked your approach. It was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a `FactoryBean` like

```
public class MockitoFactoryBean<T> implements FactoryBean<T> {

 private Class<T> classToBeMocked;

 public MockitoFactoryBean(Class<T> classToBeMocked) {
    this.classToBeMocked = classToBeMocked;
 }


 @Override
 public T getObject() throws Exception {
     return Mockito.mock(classToBeMocked);
 }

 @Override
 public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return classToBeMocked;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isSingleton() {
    return true;
 }
}
```

In your `test-context.xml` you have to add the following lines.

```
 <bean id="serviceUtilMock"  class="MockitoFactoryBean">
   <constructor-arg value="your.package.ServiceUtil" />
 </bean>
```

If you don't use XML configuration, then you have to add the equivalent to above in your Java configuration.

Comment: Do I have to change anything to the class that has to be tested? I tried to instantiate the ServiceUtils object in the Test class using this factory but the result is the same

@Mock
private ServiceUtils util = factoryBean.getObject();

Comment: You have to add the FactoryBean in your test-context.xml. I edited the answer.